# How to specify a default source address for outgoing traffic with netctl?

Tags: linux, netctl

My machine has multiple static IP addresses on the ethernet interface, which are configured with netctl.

The configuration file of netctl looks like:

```
Description='A basic static ethernet connection'
Interface=ens0
Connection=ethernet
IP=static
Address=('6.6.200.5/32' '6.6.100.23/22')
Gateway='6.6.6.1'
DNS=('1.1.1.1')
```

I would like to make `6.6.200.5/32` the default source IP address for outgoing packets. But the route table always has `6.6.100.23/22` be the default. Then, I have to run

```
ip route change default via 6.6.6.1 src 6.6.200.5 dev ens0
```

manually to override it everytime after booting.

My question is: it is possible to specify the default source address in the configuration file of netctl?